# Color over color: how to get the resulting color?

Tags: colors, transparency

I have the next task:

- let's say, there are two colors: color1 and color2
- color1 is semi-transparent (color2 maybe too)
- I know ARGB values of color1 and color2
- how to get the ARGB value of color which you get by overlaying color1 and color2 and vice versa?

Here is an image of what I am looking for:
[image]

And here is a code snippet (C#):

```
    private Color getOverlapColor(Color frontColor, Color backColor)
    {
        //return...
    }
```

Comment: That depends on the blend mode. Should easy enough to determine by looking at the ARGB value of the blended color. Or maybe not :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to assume a linear scale.

```
int blend(int front, int back, int alpha)
    => back + (front - back) * alpha / 255;
```

And then:

```
Color getOverlapColor(Color front, Color back)
{
    var r = blend(front.Red, back.Red, front.Alpha);
    var g = blend(front.Green, back.Green, front.Alpha);
    var b = blend(front.Blue, back.Blue, front.Alpha);
    var a = unsure;
    return new Color(r, g, b, a);
}
```

I'm unsure about how to calculate the resulting alpha:

- if both `front.Alpha` and `back.Alpha` are 0, the resulting is also 0.
- if `front.Alpha` is 0, the result is `back.Alpha`.
- if `front.Alpha` is 255, the value of `back.Alpha` doesn't matter.
- if `front.Alpha` and `back.Alpha` are both 50%, the result must be larger than 50%.

But I'm sure someone already figured out all of the above. Some SVG renderer, or GIMP, or some other image processing library should already have this code, carefully tested and proven in practice.